# Please help. Trying to make simple tic tac toe app with android studio. getting error

Tags: java, android

Ok so I am trying to make a tic tac toe game with android studio. I'm running into an error when trying to run the app

```
Error:(119, 69) error: cannot find symbol variable lib_bg.
```

I have searched high and low and can't figure out what the problem is. It is referring to a **R.java** file which is self generated which confuses me but obviously can't find these *.png* image files. I have confirmed these image files are in the project archive. The r.java file doesn't reference anything to these files. I'm lost please help!

```
       public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    requestFocus();

    Drawable mDrawableBg = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lib_bg);
    //noinspection deprecation
    setBackgroundDrawable(mDrawableBg);

    mBmpPlayer1 = getResBitmap(R.drawable.lib_cross);
    mBmpPlayer2 = getResBitmap(R.drawable.lib_circle);
```

Comment: Please dont paste your full code like that, you wont get nothing but downvotes... ;( [please, kindly check this link to ask nice questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: do you have a png called lib_bg ?

Comment: The exception points to this line: `Drawable mDrawableBg = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lib_bg);` so I'm guessing that `lib_bg` does not exist there.

Comment: Sorry Jordi Castilla. Black_belt yes I do have these 2 files i am getting the error on.

Comment: Dragondraikk could you elaborate a little more? I'm very new to this.

Comment: Do you have the pictures in the res>drawable directory of your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message:

```
Error:(119, 69) error: cannot find symbol variable lib_bg.
```

looks like a **compilation** error.

<sup>(If you are seeing it at runtime, then you must be ignoring compilation errors and attempting to run code that doesn't compile.  That is a **bad idea**.  Fix the compilation errors before you attempt to run the code.)</sup>

The compilation error is saying that there is no variable called `lib_bg`.  In the code you have shown us, you are referencing it here:

```
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lib_bg);
```

As you say, the `R` class is generated automatically.  In this case it is generated from your layout XML file.

I suspect that what has happened is that you have created or updated the XML file to refer to a drawable resource, but you haven't changed your Java source code to use the correct variable name for the resource.

This Android documentation page has examples showing how the XML, the resource directory and your source code are supposed to line up for a resource reference:

- [Android > Develop > API Guides > Drawable Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

---

If the XML file does refer to the resource with the correct name, then the problem may be that you need to force your Android IDE to regenerate the "R.java" file.